# Rebasing with unwanted untracked files. Error merging

Tags: git, merge, rebase

I've come across this problem a few times and I have not been able to find an answer yet. Apologies if it turns out to be a duplicate.

Suppose I have the three following commits:
A -- B -- C
(In each commit new files were added).

At some point I want to edit commit A, so I `rebase -i` and mark A for edit. Unfortunately, I use Sublime as my editor and I mistakenly save one of the files that were committed in C (say file.cpp) while I am editing A. Upon doing `git status` now there is an untracked file, as expected.

Now once I have made the edits to A that I wanted, I forget about the untracked file and I do `git rebase --continue`. Upon reaching commit C, I get the error

```
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
file.cpp
```

What should I do at this point? I've tried `git stash` followed by `git rebase --continue`, but now I end up with A -- B commits instead of A -- B -- C.

Thanks.

Comment: If you run `git status` at that point, the output should include what Git commands you can run to accept either version of the file.

Answer (score 1):

Upon finding such a file, you're left *before* the new commit is applied. `git stash` does nothing, because the only thing left is that untracked file.

You can then `git add file.cpp`, `git stash`, `git rebase --continue`, `git stash pop` and all will be fine. Just tested with 2.18.

Answer (score 0):

After you've cleaned up the untracked files (e.g. stashed or removed) you can:

```
git apply -3 .git/rebase-apply/patch
git rebase --continue
```

The `-3` flag makes it fall back to 3 way merge as `git rebase` would normally do leaving your working tree in a conflict resolution state (if any merge conflicts happen), otherwise if change applies cleanly, you should be good to continue.